# How to pass the answer to variable in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please take a look at the code first:

```
int result = 0;
result = Convert.ToInt32((correctAnswer / 5) * 100);
```

When I debug the program, Correct Answer get the value 4. But it doesn't pass the value to result. correctAnswer is intger, and I tried

```
result = ((correctAnswer / 5) * 100);
```

I know there is simple error and I cannot seem to find it. Thank you

Comment: Pay attention, you are using integer division here. 4/5 = 0 * 100 = 0

Comment: I assume that `correctAnswer`is declared as `int`. Then integer division is applied, and 4/5 = 0 (the remainder is discarded in integer division), 0*100 = 0 and `result` ends being 0 again.

Comment: if you change to `result = Convert.ToInt32((correctAnswer / 5d) * 100);` it will work. The `d` denotes a double value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer division discards decimals. You need to force it to use floating-point division by making at least one side of the division a [floating-point number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types). Using `5.0` is enough to do that:

```
result = Convert.ToInt32((correctAnswer / 5.0) * 100);
```

Or, as mentioned in the comments, you can use `5d`, which tells the compiler to make it a [`double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double). A full list of suffixes you can use are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types-table)